# MongoDB query on a field with integer value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to do a find query using a string and a number as fields. The query works while looking for the string alone. How can I make it work for number as well?

```
var check = request.body.cookie; // String
var tok = request.body.token; // It's a number

db.collection("users").find({'name':check, 'token':tok}).toArray(function(err, rows) {
    if(!rows.length)    
    {
    console.log("No data found");
    }
});
```

A sample collection is given below

```
> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("608be0dc8b83df0248ed2fc1"), "name" : "John", "age" : "18", "gender" : "M", 
"country" : "RR", "socketid" : "1",
"token" : "5907" }
```

Comment: What do you get when you try `console.log(typeof request.body.token);`

Comment: I deleted accidentially a curly bracket after the if statement - unforunately the edit queue is full...

Comment: @biberman corrected!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expression [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) condition to make sure hundred percent whatever token has type string or number,

- `$toInt` to convert string to number

```
var check = request.body.cookie; // String
var tok = request.body.token; // It's a number

db.collection("users").find({
  $and: [
    { name: check },
    {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [{ $toInt: "$token" }, tok]
      }
    }
  ]
}).toArray(function(err, rows) {
    if(!rows.length)    
        console.log("No data found");
    }
});
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yJfEEqyr1jZ)

Answer (score 2):

The `token` field is probably stored as a string in the database, not as a number. Look at the commas.

```
"token" : "5907"
```

Try converting `tok` to a string in the query.

```
find({'name':check, 'token':String(tok)})
```

Comment: This works as well. A simple fix!! Thanks!!